# Tensorflow Object Detection API: Corrupted training images in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

Im using TensorFlow Object Detection API with TensorFlow 2 and I have a problem with the training images that are displayed in TensorBoard like this:

[image]

even though the evaluation images look normally, so the problem is not in the data serialization.

[image]

To make sure that it is not done by image augmentation, I let only horizontal flip in the config file. See the full config file:

```
model {
  center_net {
    num_classes: 3
    feature_extractor {
      type: "resnet_v1_50_fpn"
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    object_detection_task {
      task_loss_weight: 1.0
      offset_loss_weight: 1.0
      scale_loss_weight: 0.1
      localization_loss {
        l1_localization_loss {
        }
      }
    }
    object_center_params {
      object_center_loss_weight: 1.0
      min_box_overlap_iou: 0.7
      max_box_predictions: 100
      classification_loss {
        penalty_reduced_logistic_focal_loss {
          alpha: 2.0
          beta: 4.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

train_config: {

  batch_size: 5
  num_steps: 10000

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer: {
      epsilon: 1e-7  # Match tf.keras.optimizers.Adam's default.
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.3e-3
          total_steps: 10000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.3e-3
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false

  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/ObjectDetection/FaceMaskDetection/Zoo/centernet_resnet50_v1_fpn_512x512_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "fine_tune"
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "C:/ObjectDetection/FaceMaskDetection/Dataset/TFRecord/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/ObjectDetection/FaceMaskDetection/Dataset/TFRecord/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "C:/ObjectDetection/FaceMaskDetection/Dataset/TFRecord/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/ObjectDetection/FaceMaskDetection/Dataset/TFRecord/eval.record"
  }
}
```

Im using `centernet_resnet50_v1_fpn_512x512_coco17_tpu-8`. The weird thing is that both loss and mAP look reasonable and I think that I wont be able to get those numbers with such bad training images. Is it just some visualization error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I also got the same problem. I am pretty confident that my TFRecords are fine, since I use them with our own training toolkit. Also, validation visualization does not expose any problems. I believe the training images are re-normalized (multiplied by 255) somewhere before saving to summaries, which causes this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll run into similar issues before, you're images are most likely fine. This seems to be a Tensorboard/Tensorflow normalization error that affects the visualization in Tensorboard. There is an extensive issue about this here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9115

You can read the details here and overall the only downside is that the image looks weird in Tensorboard.